# I want to create a new directory in Dynamic way in my storage

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am new in android my question is that,How can I create a dynamic folder means when a user click create folder text  a user can make a new folder in storage. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your Folder Name");

if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
}
```

and add this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```